# Underscore between digits

Tags: java, int, java-7

Mistakenly an underscore has been added like below:

```
int i = 1_5;
```

But no compilation error. Why is so? Output is coming as if underscore is ignored. Then why such feature in Java?

Comment: Valid since Java 7...

Comment: Its a feature.  Helps with large numbers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See [Underscores in Numeric Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html):

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can
>   appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature
>   enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric
>   literals, which can improve the readability of your code.

You didn't give a good example since 15 is readable even without separating the digits to `1_5`. But take for example the number: 100000000000, it's hard to tell what is it without counting digits, so you can do:

```
100_000_000_000
```

which makes it easier to identify the number.

In your example, try:

```
int i = 1_5;
System.out.println(i); //Prints 15
```

Comment: If only there was some way we could put comments next to code :/

Comment: We must not provide comments in order to clarify the language semantics, instead we must learn the language (or use google / stackoverflow).

Answer (score 5):

That is the new feature, valid since Java 7. It improves readability of your literal values.

According to Mala Gupta's OCA_Java_SE_7_Programmer_I_Certification_Guide_Exam_1Z0-803:

Pay attention to the use of underscores in the numeric literal values. Here are some of
the rules:

> 1) You can’t start or end a literal value with an underscore.
>
> 2) You can’t place an underscore right after the prefixes 0b, 0B, 0x,
>   and 0X, which are used to define binary and hexadecimal literal
>   values.
>
> 3) You can place an underscore right after the prefix 0, which is used
>   to define an octal literal value.
>
> 4) You can’t place an underscore prior to an L suffix (the L suffix is
>   used to mark a literal value as long).
>
> 5) You can’t use an underscore in positions where a string of digits
>   is expected.

Valid examples:

```
long baseDecimal = 100_267_760;
long octVal = 04_13;
long hexVal = 0x10_BA_75;
long binVal = 0b1_0000_10_11;
```

Invalid examples:

```
int intLiteral = _100;
int intLiteral2 = 100_999_;
long longLiteral = 100_L;
```